# validate column order during CSV file import

Tags: c#, .net, csv, model-view-controller

My company has CSV files of customer leads which need to be imported to our CRM. I need the imported CSV file columns to be in this order before it can be a successful import. In some cases, user error might occur and **First Name** could come first if they do not format the columns properly. In order to prevent the whole file being imported this way, I need to check and see if all the columns match up in this order:

1. Company Name
2. First Name
3. Last Name
4. Job Title
5. Email
6. Street Address
7. City
8. State
9. Zip
10. Phone
11. Mobile
12. Fax
13. WebURL

So far what I have does not properly validate whether or not Company Name comes first, instead it just saves whatever column A is in the CSV as Company Name. I've tried quite a few things similar to this but no luck. I'm having trouble finding the logic behind writing the code. **NOTE:** what I have written does not read the column headers, which I'm sure this is where my problem is.

**Controller:**

```
         [HttpPost]
     public ActionResult LeadProcessImport(HttpPostedFileBase FileUpload)
     {
         DataTable dt = new DataTable();
         if (FileUpload == null)
         {
             TempData["Message"] = "";
             return View();
         }


         string ext = Path.GetExtension(FileUpload.FileName);
         if (FileUpload.ContentLength > 0)
         {

             string fileName = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload.FileName);
             string path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Content/images"), fileName);


             try
             {
                 FileUpload.SaveAs(path);

                 dt = ProcessCSV(path);

                 foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
                 {
                     Lead leadImport = new Lead();

                     // order I need columns to appear in CSV
                     // 

                     leadImport.CompanyName = row[0].ToString();
                     leadImport.FirstName = row[1].ToString();
                     leadImport.LastName = row[2].ToString();
                     leadImport.Title = row[3].ToString();
                     leadImport.Email = row[4].ToString();
                     leadImport.StreetAddress = row[5].ToString();
                     leadImport.City = row[6].ToString();
                     leadImport.State_Province = row[7].ToString();
                     leadImport.Zip_PostalCode = row[8].ToString();
                     leadImport.Phone = row[9].ToString();
                     leadImport.Mobile = row[10].ToString();
                     leadImport.Fax = row[11].ToString();
                     leadImport.WebURL = row[12].ToString();
                     leadImport.LeadSource = 1;
                     leadImport.LeadStatus = 2;

                     // If string "Company Name" in header does not appear
                     // first, dump the Datatable and return to different page

                     // no workie
                     if (leadImport.CompanyName != row[0].ToString())
                     {
                         dt.Dispose();
                         return Redirect(Url.Action("LeadProcess"));

                     }
                     else
                         // if all columns are in correct order, carry on
                         // with the import
                     {
                         db.Leads.Add(leadImport);
                     }


                 }
                 db.SaveChanges();

             }
             catch (Exception ex)
             {

                 ViewData["Feedback"] = ex.Message;
             }
         }
         else
         {

             ViewData["Feedback"] = "Please select a file";
         }

         dt.Dispose();
         return Redirect(Url.Action("Index"));
     }
```

Comment: You will need to check the Column Headers in your `ProcessCSV` method. This stops the import before loading it all into a `DataTable`

Comment: `leadImport.CompanyName` will ALWAYS match `row[0].ToString()` because you're setting this value above the condition. (first line right after you create the `Lead` object)

Comment: I know I needed to, but I wasn't sure where exactly the problem with the headers lied. I'm still a n00b to .NET MVC so this was probably a silly question to you guys. I appreciate the help. I'll try it out.

Comment: I'd check the number of rows in the line. If the count doesn't match 13, you know right away it's not going to match the format.

Comment: the number of rows change each CSV file. More so I need to tell the ProcessCSV method to make sure Company Name string is getting read first, then fName, lName, Title, etc... Just figuring out how to do so

Answer (score 0):

If you are parsing CSV I would recommend that you use a tool like [CsvHelper](https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper). We have been using it for a very similar task. It has all sorts of awesome configuration.

```
var csvConfiguration = new CsvConfiguration
{
    Quote = '"',
    Delimiter = ",",
    TrimFields = true,
    TrimHeaders = true,
    QuoteNoFields = false,
    QuoteAllFields = false,
    HasHeaderRecord = true,
    IsHeaderCaseSensitive = false,
    WillThrowOnMissingField = false
};

var field = csvReader.GetField("YourFieldName"),
```

It also has a very nice [mapping functionality](https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper/wiki/Fluent-Class-Mapping)

Comment: but how csv helper validates column order and column names? Because I am using csv helper but it process csv without throwing exception for column order and column name